# Django ImportError: dlopen(_mysql.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_mysql_affected_rows'

Tags: python, django, mysql-python, apple-silicon

I am setting up local workspace for my Django project with MySQL on a Macbook AIR with *M2 chip*. All config are migrated from my old Macbook Pro with *core i7* using OSX *Migration Assistant*.

I am having problem trying to run server on my local, i.e. `python manage.py runserver`. The err msg is:

```
  File "/Users/.../.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/.../.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

- MySQL server is set up on my local and works fine.
- I am able to use mysql to connect to my local MySQL server, i.e. `mysql -u root -p`
- `mysqlclient` is installed, the version is `2.1.1`
- While importing `MySQLdb` directly using python console, it seems python is having difficulty using `dlopen` to open the "c compiled" (not sure how this is called exactly) file, or it opened but there was error? Error as:

```
Python 3.10.6 (v3.10.6:9c7b4bd164, Aug  1 2022, 17:13:48) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/.../.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_mysql_affected_rows'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/.../.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

- Tried uninstall and reinstall without using cache: `python -m pip download mysqlclient==2.1.1 --no-binary :all:`, no luck.
- Tried upgrading mysqlclient (2.2.0.2 was installed), Django directly asking if mysqlclient is installed.

Thanks for advance!

Comment: Check for compatibility between your python version and MySQL client. Sometimes that also creates an issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm also running into this issue.

MacOS 13.4.1
Python 3.10.0

I accidentally upgraded to MySQL 8.1 using brew and the libmysqlclient.21.dylib no longer exists, but libmysqlclient.22.dylib. Both my mysql and mysql-client are using this new dylib file.

It appears that mysqlclient==2.2.0 is still looking for libmysqlclient.21.dylib.

I've tried reverting back to MySQL 8.0.34, but now my database fails saying it can no longer go backwards due to the upgrade:
"[InnoDB] Cannot boot server version 80034 on data directory built by version 80100. Downgrade is not supported"

--

I've opened a discussion about it with the PyMySQL github:
https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/discussions/652

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34922472)